# how to display different category post on different page but with same template?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have two category under my category

1. My-Category
2. Uncategorized

I have created one template "My-template" and using that template i have created two different pages called "Page-1" and "Page-2".

I want to display posts from "My-Category" in "Page-1" and posts from "Uncategorized" in "Page-2".

Is there any way i can achive this?
I don't want to use plugin or already created template because i want to do this for learning.

```
query_posts('post_in=39');
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
echo '<div class="box">';
?>
<div <?php post_class("posttitle");?>><?php     the_title();?></div>
<div <?php post_class("postcontent");?>><?php   the_content();?></div>
<?php
echo "</div>";
endwhile;
```